# Passing counters to jQuery click functions in for loops

Tags: javascript, jquery

The buttons below output their numbers in the console when clicked. Fire 1 should output 1, Fire 2 should output 2, and so on.

I am using a `for` loop to pass 1–4 to the functions that call `fire(n)`, but the output is never what I expect when I click any of the buttons. I tried following an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606438/jquery-click-function-in-for-loop-only-working-in-last-loop), but it is not working for me.

If I use the code I commented out instead of the `for` loop, everything works fine. Why will this not work if I use the `for` loop?

```js
function fire(n) {
    console.log(n);
}

for (var i = 1; i <= 4; ++i) {
    $("#fire" + i).on("click", fire(i));
}

/*
$("#fire" + 1).on("click", function(){fire(1)});
$("#fire" + 2).on("click", function(){fire(2)});
$("#fire" + 3).on("click", function(){fire(3)});
$("#fire" + 4).on("click", function(){fire(4)});
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="fire1">Fire 1</button>
<button id="fire2">Fire 2</button>
<button id="fire3">Fire 3</button>
<button id="fire4">Fire 4</button>
```

Comment: `on("click", fire(i));` you are calling `fire` not setting it as a callback

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: there is no need for using `for` in this example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a *function* to the click handler.  You are passing `undefined`.  This is because `fire(i)` *runs* the function, so you are setting its *return* value - `undefined` - as the handler.

You need to generate a *new* function for each iteration - a closure - to "capture" each `i` value.

```
function fire(n) {
    return function(){
        console.log(n);
    }
}

for (var i = 1; i <= 4; ++i) {
    $("#fire" + i).on("click", fire(i));
}
```

Notice how now the `fire()` function is *returning* something.  It's returning a function.  A different one for each click handler, one that "captures" each iteration's `i` value.

Comment: Isn't that what's known as a closure?

Comment: @user1958756: Yeah.  Because it's "closing" around the `n` value.

Comment: So basically, I just needed to add `return function(){ }` around `console.log()` so `fire()` has something to return? Thanks anyway!

Comment: @JonKantner: Basically, yeah.  What I am doing is making `fire()` return a (new) function each time it's called.

Answer (score 3):

When you are doing `$("#fire" + i).on("click", fire(i));` you are actually calling the `fire` function. What you would like to do is to bind the parameter of the method.

One simple way to do that is to make a function that returns a new function with the correct value, which can then be added to your listener.

```
function fire(n) {
    return function() {
        console.log(n);
    }
}
```

Another way could be to use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), which does this for you. Something like

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; ++i) {
    $("#fire" + i).on("click", fire.bind(this, i));
}
```

The first parameter is what to use for `this` when calling the function, and then the next parameters are parameters to the original function.

Answer (score 0):

Since each button id has the information that you want to extract and use in your loop i propose the following workaround.

```js
function fire(n) {
    console.log(n);
}

$('button[id^=fire]').on('click',function() {
fire(this.id.split("fire")[1]);
});

/*
$("#fire" + 1).on("click", function(){fire(1)});
$("#fire" + 2).on("click", function(){fire(2)});
$("#fire" + 3).on("click", function(){fire(3)});
$("#fire" + 4).on("click", function(){fire(4)});
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="fire1">Fire 1</button>
<button id="fire2">Fire 2</button>
<button id="fire3">Fire 3</button>
<button id="fire4">Fire 4</button>
```